# How is MIME type "text/html" registered to shared-mime-info? Where is its *.xml file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mime-types

On Ubuntu 10.10, which XML file under the directory `/usr/share/mime/applications` is for MIME type `text/html`?

I checked `xml.xml` and `xhtml+xml.xml`, but neither has a glob pattern of `*.html`.
So where is this file format entry?

Answer (score 1):

This should help. This search was done on Debian 6, but should be the same on Ubuntu.

```
#$find /usr/share/mime/ -print0 | xargs -0 grep [.]html 
/usr/share/mime/globs2:50:text/html:*.html
/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml:    <glob pattern="*.html"/>
/usr/share/mime/globs:text/html:*.html
/usr/share/mime/text/html.xml:  <glob pattern="*.html"/>
```

From this you can see the information is in `/usr/share/mime/globs`, `/usr/share/mime/globs2`, `/usr/share/mime/text/html.xml` and `/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml`